# Project structure strategy for CI/CD

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

Im working on a project that will use Gitlabs CI/CD. Each part of the project will be in a Docker container as seperate microservice.
Project elements:

```
Project
|- Product Factory (console script)
|- Product Shipment (console script, sends product via email)
|- Product Website
|- API for Website
|- Database
|- Base (just `docker-compose.yml` file)
```

Wheres the problem? This is my first project which will use Docker and Gitlabs CI/CD and I would like to do it "right".

I would like to ask some experienced developers for advice whether my idea for dev/deploy (which You can read about below) is good or am I missing something.

- Every project element (all 6 of them) has its own, seperate GIT repo
- Every project element has (of course) its own Dockerfile
- After `git push` on any of the elements, GitLab will start a runner that builds the Docker Image from last commit in that GIT repo and upload it to Dockers Registry. It will not deploy it to production server yet.
- Next, after the Docker Image is uploaded, a runner would trigger `Base Repo` build process (via [GitLabs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)), which will login to a production server, upload `docker-compose.yml`, download latest images and restart all containers.

My only concern about this idea is that (for example) sometimes I might update `Database` layout and code in each Element of the Project that will use it. In this case the `Base trigger` should not be executed before every Project Elements Docker Image is not build and uploaded to Registry.

I have spent last couple of days on reading Dockers and GitLabs CI/CD documentation and this is what I came up with ;). What you think about it?